Import Swift protocol from SubModule into Objective-C Class
need some light here!
Been working on a app where some submodules (.xcproject) are written in swift, and some inner modules of the main target are written in ObjC.
Until then all good.
We want to implement a feature from one of the swift submodule into an ObjC class.
Our way for the rest of the project is to import every dependencies to a Parent class through an extension conforming to the protocol.
Example.
// In Swift

@obc public protocol MyProtocol { }

class ParentClass: MyProtocol { } // this way all the children gets access to the parent conformance

class ChildClass: ParentClass { }

In my bridging header, (which is already found, and works correctly by the way), I added:
#import <MySubModule/MySubModule.h>

In my ObjC class, I import MainApp-Swift.h
Now when importing the same protocol, I get this error:
Cannot find protocol declaration for MyProtocolFromSubModule
Although the submodule is added and the protocol is found in the MainApp-Swift.h
@interface SomeClassIExtend (SWIFT_EXTENSION(MainApp)) <MyProtocolFromSubModule>
@end

Ideas ?
EDIT SOLUTION FOUND
It might have been obvious but still want to share it.
Since swift is ObjectiveC c friendly, and my protocol holds object that be identified by ObjectiveC, turning the protocol into a an ObjectiveC one resolved my issue.
Still have to make it public in my submodule and export it, but once its done, can reach by #importing my module.
Yeah !

You don't need import MainApp-Swift.h. You need just import modules that have protocol.

The protocol is still invisible to the objc class tho
